# I will have offended every breathing entity

Tags: perfect-constructions, future-perfect

*It doesn't occur to me that I haven't exactly showered him with love and adoration and overt affection, nor does it occur to me that within five seconds **I will have offended every breathing entity** within my radius and not have a clue why.*

I would like to ask whether it would be a mistake to use just simple future tense instead of perfect future in the passage in bold in the above sentence? The excerpt is an internal monologue from one short story.

Comment: Typo: a clue *why*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Within five seconds I will offend every breathing entity

This means in five seconds you will start to offend, or be in the process of offending "every breathing entity."  Something later in the story could interrupt this.

> Within five seconds I will have offended every breathing entity

This means in five seconds, your process of offending "every breathing entity" will be completed.  This is an atomic completed event that will happen and it's not open to being interrupted.